# Recording and charting boot process information in Linux

Tags: linux, process, boot, c, c++

I need to write a command line tool that records the boot process information in Linux, and then renders it in a chart format (a textual chart would do). How do I ***programmatically*** obtain the this boot process information? Languages that I am allowed to use are C and C++.

Comment: http://www.bootchart.org/

Comment: @badp: Thanks. I am aware of that application. This is a homework assignment, so I cannot show my professor some existing application.

Comment: This question may be too board. I'm tempted to answer "parse the log files" but I'm not sure whether that's the information you need. Please consider breaking the question down to several ones like "How do I monitor memory usage during boot?".

Comment: While you can't turn in an existing application, I imagine that the source code for a program that does exactly what you want to do, might be a useful resource in hunting down the solution.

Comment: In particular, the Data Collection section of the [Bootchart "How it Works"](http://www.bootchart.org/docs.html) page explains exactly what it does

Answer (score 4):

Well, if no-one else is writing answer for this question (instead of valid comments), I'll do it.

[bootchart.org](http://bootchart.org) is tool for doing exactly this.

> Bootchart is a tool for performance analysis and visualization of the GNU/Linux boot process.

There is rather good page explaining how it works: [Bootchart - How it works?](http://www.bootchart.org/docs.html). In short, it's wrapper for normal `init` script. See for example [this document](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialInitProcess.html) for more information on `init`.

That wrapper script then starts normal `init` and collects statistics from various places (`/proc/stat`, `/proc/diskstats`, `/proc/[PID]/stat`) as early as possible.